# IIS 6 Logs M.I.A

Tags: iis-6, logfiles

I'm trying to find my IIS log files and I seem to be having a problem.

First off I've gone into IIS and right clicked on the site in question and selected properties...

Under the Web Site tab **I have the Enable Logging check box checked**.

The active log format is set to **W3C Extended Log File Format**.

To get where the log files should be being stored I click the Properties button next to the log format drop down list. It has this path as `C:\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles`. Then below that input box it has the log file name as `W3SVC1919798527\exyymmdd.log`

The problem is that the folder `W3SVC1919798527` doesn't exist in the `C:\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles` folder... nor does it appear to exist on the PC anywhere... What am I doing wrong? Where can I find the log files for this site? Or am I totally misunderstanding what a log file is and where to find it?

Thanks

Comment: superuser or serverfault would be more appropriate I suppose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I had to check the Log Visits check box on the Home Directory tab when viewing the properties dialog box of the web site in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Is logging enabled for the site?
How about searching for anything that ends with .log?  Or has w3svc in it?

Comment: If all it takes is for Logging to be turned on is having the "Enable Logging" check box under the web site properties, "Web Site" tab checked then yes, logging is enabled. There are other .log files in the 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles' folder within other various folders begining with 'W3SVC*'.